# Simple Maven Mojo Plug-in: Boolean parameter

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

This should be simple - I think I'm just overlooking something.  I have a simple Mojo:

```
package com.company.product.plugins;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;

/**
 * @goal diff
 */
public class CCDiffMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    /**
     * @parameter expression="${ccdiff.run}" default-value="true"
     */
    private boolean run;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        if (run) {
            getLog().info("Executing...");
            // TODO: Execute.
        } else {
            getLog().info("Skipping.");
        }
    }
}
```

And the pom.xml contents:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company.product.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>ccdiff</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Content Catalog Diff</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is all pretty much pulled from the [Maven plugin development guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html).

So, it appears I can do:

```
$ mvn com.company.product.plugins:ccdiff:diff
```

And this works to execute the branch where I'm going to plop in the logic for this custom tool (it's kind of an XML diff).  The boolean parameter is a flag that will allow somebody to turn off the execution when doing a build of the larger project.  However, when I try:

```
$ mvn com.company.product.plugins:ccdiff:diff -Dccdiff.run=false
```

It still displays the "Executing..." message, meaning the parameter isn't getting set for some reason.

Any ideas?  I feel it's just going to be one of these "D'oh!" errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal is called diff ... `@goal diff`, so try command line  without 'cc' as follows:

```
$ mvn com.company.product.plugins:ccdiff:diff -Ddiff.run=false
```

**EDIT : Take 2.**

I created the project as you have it, and it works for me just like you have it.
I'm running maven 2.2.1, here's the output :

```
C:\java\ws\ccdiff>set MAVEN_OPTS=-DXms_1024M -DXmx=2048M
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] artifact com.company.product.plugins:ccdiff: checking for updates from central
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - com.company.product.plugins:ccdiff:maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [com.company.product.plugins:ccdiff:diff]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ccdiff:diff {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Executing...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 23 16:27:10 CAT 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 1M/4M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\java\ws\ccdiff>mvn com.company.product.plugins:ccdiff:diff -Dccdiff.run=false

C:\java\ws\ccdiff>set MAVEN_OPTS=-DXms_1024M -DXmx=2048M
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - com.company.product.plugins:ccdiff:maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [com.company.product.plugins:ccdiff:diff]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ccdiff:diff {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Skipping.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 23 16:27:20 CAT 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 1M/4M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\java\ws\ccdiff>
```

Comment: Nope, this still doesn't work.  I have the parameter expression referencing `ccdiff.run`, which I thought needs to match up.  I'll try changing that to `${diff.run}` to see if that works (Ed. No dice on that, either).

Comment: Weird.  I copied out both the Mojo and the pom file to a separate directory to replicate the issue outside of the existing project.  I got this instead: `Required goal not found: com.company.product.plugins:ccdiff:diff in com.company.product.plugins:ccdiff:1.0-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: Turns out I was missing the src/main/java directory among other things - and had to include maven-compiler-plugin with source/target set to 1.5...